# Difference between Dynamic Environment Variables and Normal Environment Variables in CMD

Tags: cmd, environment-variables, command-prompt

I was reading an article on [ss64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) about Environment variables in Command Prompt.

Later in the article there exists a *table* which states environment variables found commonly in Command Prompt. Some of the variables listed there are termed as **Volatile** (Read Only). A sentence found in the article states:-

> Dynamic environment variables are read-only and are computed each time the variable is expanded. When all variables are listed with SET, these will not appear in the list. Do not attempt to directly SET a dynamic variable.

I understood the later two statements. But i can't understand the first one.

***Doubts:-***

- `%userprofile%` is an *non-volatile* variable, which resolves to `%SystemDrive%\Users\{username}`, and `%homepath%` is a *volatile* variable which resolves to `Users\{Username}`. Both commands are quite similar (except for the `systemdrive`). Then why is one volatile and the other one non-volatile?
- What is the criteria for a variable to be dynamic? what makes `%appdata%` (just an ex.) an non volatile variable?
- Dynamic Variables are computed each time the variable is expanded, this makes sense for variables like `%CD% %DATE% %TIME% %RANDOM%` etc. as they would lose their functionality if they would be *non-volatile*. But how would it effect `%homepath%`?
- Some *non-volatile* variables have sort-of dynamic components in them. Ex. `%userprofile%` has `%SystemDrive%` and `{username}` in it's path. Then how are those variables not dynamic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three types of variables of which value is accessed using the syntax `%variable%` or `!variable!` on having enabled delayed environment variable expansion with using the option `EnableDelayedExpansion` of the command `setlocal` from within a Windows command prompt window or a batch file, i.e. using `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe`.

### 1. Persistent stored variables

There are **environment** variables stored persistent in Windows registry.

1. **User** variables stored in Windows registry under the key:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
   ```
2. **System** variables stored in Windows registry under the key:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
   ```

The **user** variables are defined for just the account in which user registry hive they are stored (file `%UserProfile%\ntuser.dat`). The **system** variables are defined for all accounts used on a Windows machine (file `%SystemRoot%\System32\config\SYSTEM`).

The persistent stored variables can be viewed, edited and deleted by opening the Windows **Control Panel**, clicking on **System**, clicking next (on left side) on **Advanced system settings** and clicking on button **Environment Variables**. The upper half is for the **user** variables of the current user account and the lower half is for the **system** variables since Windows XP.

There are defined by default as **user** variables only `TEMP` and `TMP` since Windows XP.

The list of predefined **system variables** is since Windows XP:

```
ComSpec
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS
OS
PATH
PATHEXT
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER
PROCESSOR_LEVEL
PROCESSOR_REVISION
TEMP
TMP
windir
```

There is on Windows Vista and newer Windows versions defined by default also the **system** variable `PSModulePath`.

None of the predefined **system** variables with exception of `PATH` and `PATHEXT` should be deleted or modified ever as this could cause lots of troubles which can even result in Windows not starting anymore. I would strongly recommend using a virtual machine on experimenting with the predefined **system** variables for which a backup of the entire virtual machine image exists before starting the experiments.

#### 1.1 Backup of persistent stored variables

It is advisable to make a backup of the **user** and **system** variables before playing around with them by opening a command prompt window and running for example:

```
md C:\VariablesBackup 2>nul
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe EXPORT HKCU\Environment "C:\VariablesBackup\UserVariables.reg"
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe EXPORT "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" "C:\VariablesBackup\SystemVariables.reg"
```

#### 1.2 Restore of persistent stored variables

Restoring the **user** variables can be done from within a command prompt window **on having made a backup before** with:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe DELETE "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /f
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe IMPORT "C:\VariablesBackup\UserVariables.reg"
```

Restoring the **system** variables can be done from within a command prompt window opened **as administrator on having made a backup before** with:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe DELETE HKCU\Environment /f
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe IMPORT "C:\VariablesBackup\SystemVariables.reg"
```

It is advisable to restart Windows on having restored **user** and **system** variables from a backup to make sure that really all processes use the restored variables.

#### 1.3 Modification of `PATH` with a batch file

Batch file programmers thinking about modification of **user** or **system** `PATH` with a batch file should read first:

- [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564)
- [Why are other folder paths also added to system PATH with SetX and not only the specified folder path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25919222/3074564)
- [How can I use a .bat file to remove specific tokens from the PATH environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38664286/3074564)
- [How to search and replace a string in environment variable PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24650324/3074564)
- [Adding the current directory to Windows path permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47080452/3074564)

**ATTENTION:** It is an absolute **NO GO - NEVER EVER** to use command **SETX** with `%PATH%` in a batch file to modify **user** or **system** `PATH` variable.

The only reason to modify **user** or **system** `PATH` with a batch file on installation of a program (executable or script) is that this program is designed for being mainly used by users from the Windows command line. A program is bad designed if it requires that its directory or one of its subdirectories is in `PATH` to work at all. A program is very bad designed if it adds a folder path to **system** `PATH` left to the folder paths defined by default by Windows.

The **system** `PATH` variable should start always with:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
```

The Windows system directory is the directory containing most executables and dynamic linked libraries. For that reason it should be always the first directory searched for executables and libraries after the current directory.

### 2. Windows shell variables

There are a lot more Windows **environment** variables predefined as it can be seen on:

- SS64: [How-to: Windows Environment Variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)
- Wikipedia: [Environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows)

These variables are defined by Windows shell which is by default `explorer.exe` being started on Windows start as Windows shell according to registry value `Shell` under registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

The [Window shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-entry) elements noticed most by users are the Windows desktop, the Windows Start menu and the Windows taskbar with the system tray.

The Windows shell defines in its memory lots of environment variables depending on various values in Windows registry for the current user account not stored persistent in Windows registry as described above. The current list of environment variables is copied whenever a new process is created like starting an executable from Windows shell.

The list of environment variables defined by Windows shell consisting of the persistent stored **user** and **system** variables and the **shell** variables for current user account can be seen by opening a command prompt window and running the command **SET** without any additional argument.

Most of the shell variables are defined from the registry strings under

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

Most of the registry string values exist in `User Shell Folders` of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` and in `Shell Folders` of type `REG_SZ`. But there are some registry string values existing only under one of the two registry keys.

See also: [How to create a directory in the user's desktop directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58516212/3074564)
In this answer is explained in detail how Windows Explorer evaluates these registry string values and handles them on manual modification by a user using `regedit.exe` or `reg.exe` on the example of the shell folder `Desktop`.

The function [CreateEnvironmentBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-createenvironmentblock) and the private shell32 function `RegenerateUserEnvironment` are used by `explorer.exe` with [GetUserNameExW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/secext/nf-secext-getusernameexw) and [GetComputerNameExW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getcomputernameexw) to create the environment variables list copied by Windows Explorer on starting an executable from Windows shell using the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw).

See also the comments written by [Eryk Sun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryk-sun) on question [Where are the environment variables for cmd.exe stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56477874/where-are-the-environment-variables-for-cmd-exe-stored)

There are some environment variables on 64-bit Windows which depend on starting a 64-bit or a 32-bit executable. Microsoft documented them on [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details) as follows:

> **64-bit process:**
>
> PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64 **or** PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=IA64 **or** PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=ARM64
> ProgramFiles=%ProgramFiles%
> ProgramW6432=%ProgramFiles%
> CommonProgramFiles=%CommonProgramFiles%
> CommonProgramW6432=%CommonProgramFiles%
>
> **Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:** The ProgramW6432 and CommonProgramW6432 environment variables were added starting with Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2.
>
> **32-bit process:**
>
> PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
> PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
> ProgramFiles=%ProgramFiles(x86)%
> ProgramW6432=%ProgramFiles%
> CommonProgramFiles=%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%
> CommonProgramW6432=%CommonProgramFiles%

The value of the **environment** variable `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` cannot be used to find out from within a batch file if the installed Windows is a 32-bit (x86) or a 64-bit (AMD64) Windows. The value depends on processing of the batch file by either 64-bit `%SystemRoot%\Sysem32\cmd.exe` or by 32-bit `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` on 64-bit Windows.

See also the Microsoft documentations:

- [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector)
- [Registry Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector)

The usage of **environment** variables defined by the Windows shell must be done wisely on writing a batch file which should be designed for execution by other accounts on same or a different Windows machine. Many batch files working fine in environment of author of the batch file do not work in environment set up on running the same batch file as scheduled task with system account or on a different machine because of the differences in **environment** variables list.

The environment variables defined by a process on starting an executable with the Windows kernel library function `CreateProcess` determine the environment variables which the started executable can use.

Most applications use `CreateProcess` with value `null` for the parameter `lpEnvironment`. Therefore `CreateProcess` makes a copy of the current environment variables of the current process. For that reason every executable started from Windows desktop, start menu or taskbar gets the environment variables as defined by the `explorer.exe` instance running as Windows shell.

A really very good coded executable or script using environment variables which are defined by default on Windows verify explicitly that every used environment variable is really defined and use otherwise a suitable default value like `C:\Windows` on environment variable `SystemRoot` is not defined with checking if there is really a directory `C:\Windows` and exit with an appropriate error message on an important environment variable not defined before causing perhaps damage.

`SystemRoot` is an example for a Windows shell variable defined by `explorer.exe` as environment variable which is not determined by the registry string values of the shell folders. Some environment variable values should not be modified by a user at any time independent on its real source which no script author ever needs to know as being a Windows implementation detail.

### 3. Dynamic variables of Windows command processor

There are some variables listed in help of command **SET** output on running in a command prompt window `set /?` which cannot be found in the list of environment variables on running just `set`.

These variables are:

```
CD
DATE
TIME
RANDOM
ERRORLEVEL
CMDEXTVERSION
CMDCMDLINE
HIGHESTNUMANODENUMBER
```

The **dynamic** variables are **internal** variables of `cmd.exe`. So these variables are available only in a Windows command prompt window which is a running `cmd.exe` process or a batch file processed by `cmd.exe`. The **dynamic** variables are not available in other executables or scripts as these variables are **not** environment variables.

The most common used **dynamic** variables are:

1. **CD**
   The current directory path not ending with a backlash, except the current directory is the root directory of the drive.
2. **DATE**
   The current local date in format as defined for the account in region and language settings of Windows.
3. **TIME**
   The current local time in format as defined for the account in region and language settings of Windows.
4. **ERRORLEVEL**
   Exit value of previously executed command or program.
5. **RANDOM**
   A random decimal number between 0 and 32767.

There are some more **dynamic** variables, but they are rarely used in batch files.

There is additionally the variable `__AppDir__` containing the path of currently running `cmd.exe` always ending with a backslash which is not documented by Microsoft. I recommend not using this **undocumented** variable as there is no guarantee that a future version of `cmd.exe` still has this variable. `__AppDir__` is on 64-bit Windows, for example, `%SystemRoot%\System32\` on 64-bit `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` currently running, or `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\` on 32-bit `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` currently running, or any other path on copying `cmd.exe` to any other folder and starting this copy of `cmd.exe`. There are some more **undocumented dynamic** variables listed on SS64 page [How-to: Windows Environment Variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) which should be used only with special care for the same reason.

The values of the most used **dynamic** variables are changed dynamically by the Windows command processor itself while the values of the environment variables change only if command **SET** is used during execution of a batch file to redefine an **environment** variable. This is an important difference between **environment** and **dynamic** variables.

### 4. Accessing the values of dynamic variables

Every **environment** variable can be deleted or redefined in the **local** environment of a processed batch file. There is no **environment** variable read-only.

`cmd.exe` contains internally in its code the file extension list `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.JS;.WS;.MSC` which is used as value for `PATHEXT` if the **environment** variable `PATHEXT` does not exist in **local** environment variables list to be able to find nevertheless scripts and executables specified on command line or in a batch file without file extension. But `cmd.exe` does not contain a list of folder paths as fallback list if the **environment** variable `PATH` does not exist in **local** environment. So a batch file writer should be careful on modification of **local environment** variable `PATH` for whatever reason.

The values of the **dynamic** variables are referenced like the values of the **environment** variables with `%variable%` or `!variable!` on enabled [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). But the Windows command processor always searches first in the current list of **environment** variables if there is a variable with specified name. Only if there is no **environment** variable with that name, `cmd` searches next in its internal list of dynamic variables if there is one with the specified name.

The current value of a **dynamic** variable cannot be accessed anymore on definition of an **environment** variable with same name as a **dynamic** variable. For that reason a batch file writer should never use one of the **dynamic** variable names as name for an **environment** variable.

Here is a code which demonstrates what happens if a batch file writer has the really not good idea to define an **environment** variable with name `ERRORLEVEL`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
echo/
echo Define environment variable ERRORLEVEL with string value "014".
echo/
set ERRORLEVEL=014
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 12 (echo EQU: ERRORLEVEL is 12.) else echo EQU: ERRORLEVEL is not 12.
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 014 (echo  ==: ERRORLEVEL is 14.) else echo  ==: ERRORLEVEL is not 14.
if errorlevel 0 (
    if not errorlevel 1 (echo  IF: ERRORLEVEL is 0.) else echo  IF: ERRORLEVEL is greater than 0.
) else echo  IF: ERRORLEVEL is less than 0.
echo/
echo Delete the environment variable ERRORLEVEL.
echo/
set ERRORLEVEL=
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 12 (echo EQU: ERRORLEVEL is 12.) else echo EQU: ERRORLEVEL is not 12.
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 014 (echo  ==: ERRORLEVEL is 14.) else echo  ==: ERRORLEVEL is not 14.
if errorlevel 0 (
    if not errorlevel 1 (echo  IF: ERRORLEVEL is 0.) else echo  IF: ERRORLEVEL is greater than 0.
) else echo  IF: ERRORLEVEL is less than 0.
echo/
echo In all test cases the value of dynamic variable ERRORLEVEL was 0.
echo/
for %%I in (%CMDCMDLINE%) do if /I "%%~I" == "/c" pause & goto EndBatch
:EndBatch
endlocal
```

The output of this batch file is:

```
Define environment variable ERRORLEVEL with string value "014".

EQU: ERRORLEVEL is 12.
 ==: ERRORLEVEL is 14.
 IF: ERRORLEVEL is 0.

Delete the environment variable ERRORLEVEL.

EQU: ERRORLEVEL is not 12.
 ==: ERRORLEVEL is not 14.
 IF: ERRORLEVEL is 0.

In all test cases the value of dynamic variable ERRORLEVEL was 0.
```

It can be seen on [debugging the batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564) that the first **IF** condition `if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 12` results in replacing `%ERRORLEVEL%` by the string `014` because of there is the **environment** variable `ERRORLEVEL` defined with this string value. The function [wcstol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtol-wcstol-strtol-l-wcstol-l) is used by command **IF** because of operator `EQU` to convert the string `014` being interpreted as octal number because of the leading `0` and the string `12` to 32-bit signed integer values and compare them on equality. Therefore the first condition is true.

The second **IF** condition `if %ERRORLEVEL% == 014` results also in replacing `%ERRORLEVEL%` by the string `014` because of there is the **environment** variable `ERRORLEVEL` defined with this string value. But now the function [lstrcmpW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lstrcmpw) is used by command **IF** because of operator `==`. Therefore the second condition is also true.

The third **IF** condition uses the recommended syntax explained by help of command **IF** output on running `if /?` in a command prompt window. It can be seen that using the recommended syntax results in evaluation of the value of the internal **dynamic** variable `ERRORLEVEL` of Windows command processor even if an **environment** variable is defined with name `ERRORLEVEL`. The recommended syntax to evaluate the exit code of a previously executed command or program works always and anywhere within a batch file as demonstrated here.

See also:

- [What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/)
- [Which cmd.exe internal commands clear the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968009/)

Further it must be taken into account that accessing current value of a **dynamic** variable is always on variable reference being expanded by the Windows command processor and not real execution of the command or executable.

A code to demonstrate that difference:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%I in (1,1,3) do (
    echo %%DATE%% %%TIME%% is:  %DATE% %TIME%
    echo ^^!DATA^^! ^^!TIME^^! is:  !DATE! !TIME!
    echo %%RANDOM%%/^^!RANDOM^^!: %RANDOM%/!RANDOM!
    if exist %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe (
        %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 /NOBREAK >nul
    ) else (
        %SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n 4 >nul
    )
)
for %%I in (%CMDCMDLINE%) do if /I "%%~I" == "/c" pause & goto EndBatch
:EndBatch
endlocal
```

The output is for example:

```
%DATE% %TIME% is:  31.01.2021 13:54:30,67
!DATA! !TIME! is:  31.01.2021 13:54:30,68
%RANDOM%/!RANDOM!: 18841/27537
%DATE% %TIME% is:  31.01.2021 13:54:30,67
!DATA! !TIME! is:  31.01.2021 13:54:33,12
%RANDOM%/!RANDOM!: 18841/16705
%DATE% %TIME% is:  31.01.2021 13:54:30,67
!DATA! !TIME! is:  31.01.2021 13:54:36,16
%RANDOM%/!RANDOM!: 18841/32668
```

`%DATE% %TIME%` results in printing to console window three times the same date/time because of these two variable references are expanded already by the Windows command processor on parsing the entire command block before command **FOR** is executed at all. `%RANDOM%` results in printing three times the same number for the same reason while `!RANDOM!` prints usually three different numbers.

See also:

- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)
- [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/)

`if errorlevel number` and `if not errorlevel number` work also within a command block!

The **dynamic** environment variables can be accessed only with command extensions enabled as by default. Otherwise Windows command processor emulates `COMMAND.COM` behavior (more or less) of MS-DOS and Windows 95/98/ME not supporting **dynamic** variables at all as demonstrated by this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
echo/
echo With command extensions disabled:
echo/
echo Date/time is: %DATE% %TIME%
echo Current dir: "%CD%"
endlocal
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
echo/
echo With command extensions enabled:
echo/
echo Date/time is: %DATE% %TIME%
echo Current dir: "%CD%"
echo/
for %%I in (%CMDCMDLINE%) do if /I "%%~I" == "/c" pause & goto EndBatch
:EndBatch
endlocal
```

The output is for example:

```
With command extensions disabled:

Date/time is:
Current dir: ""

With command extensions enabled:

Date/time is: 31.01.2021 14:17:42,92
Current dir: "C:\Temp\Development & Test!"
```

The values of **dynamic** variables can be only read. It is not possible to modify the value of a **dynamic** variable with command **SET** as it results in the definition of an **environment** variable with the name of a **dynamic** variable which takes precedence over the **dynamic** variable.