# Not getting the required output through "find" command in a for loop in Windows Batch Scripting

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, find

My requirement is simple, i just want to scan all the files in the current directory for a particular string and if that string is found i just want a display saying "String is found" otherwise "String not found"

```
    @ECHO OFF
    for %%f in (C:\Users\aalvoor\Desktop\BatchScript\*) do (
    echo File is %%f
    find /c "defaultModel" %%f >NUL
    if %errorlevel% equ 1 (echo File is notfound) else (echo String is found)
    )
```

But the problem is it works when i am not putting it in a for loop but when i put it in for loop for some reason for every file i get a message String is found which is not true.

Comment: I recommend to open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `if /?` and read the output help which explains already on first page the recommended syntax to evaluate the exit code of a former run command or executable. So use `if errorlevel 1` instead of `if %errorlevel% equ 1` and the code works and you have not to think about delayed expansion. See also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) and chapter 4 of [this answer about dynamic variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65979943/3074564).

Comment: Extremely thankful guys..if errorlevel worked...Moreover did not have to use delayedvariable expansion logic, was struggling over this over a week. Actually used the comment given by Mofo.. So how can I mark it as accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional operators `&&` and `||`

`&&` being if `errorlevel` equ 0

`||` being if `errorlevel` neq 0

```
@echo off
for %%f in ("%userprofile%\Desktop\BatchScript\*") do (
    echo File is %%f
    find /c "defaultModel" %%f >nul 2>&1 && echo String found || echo String NOT found
)
```