# Why don't substrings work with command line arguments?

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, variables, environment-variables

In a Windows batch file, the following will work to extract all of `%1` except the last 4 characters:

```
set foo=%1
set x=%foo:~,-4%
```

But this will not work:

```
set x=%1:~,-4%
```

Why is this?

Comment: They're not the same type of variable, `%1` does not even have the same format as `%foo%`, which in itself should be a give away. BTW, for safety and readability, it should read as `set "foo=%~1"`, and `set "x=%foo:~0,-4%"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` supports string substitutions only with **environment** variables (and with **dynamic** variables), but not with batch file **arguments** (or with **loop** variables).

`foo` is an environment variable of which value is referenced with immediate expansion using `%foo%` and with delayed expansion with `!foo!`. String substitutions are supported for environment variables as described by the help output on running `set /?` in a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window. The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` supports string substitutions on **environment** (and **dynamic**) variable expansions everywhere in a command line.

For more details see [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

For an explanation of the difference between environment and dynamic variables read the long answer on [Difference between Dynamic Environment Variables and Normal Environment Variables in CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61207037/).

`%1` references an **argument** passed to the batch file. The help output on running `call /?` in a command prompt window explains how arguments can be referenced in a batch file and which modifiers are supported by the Windows command processor. String substitutions are not supported by `cmd.exe` on **argument** strings.

For completeness the help output on running `for /?` explains how a **loop** variable can be referenced inside the body of a loop and which modifiers are available (the same as for argument references). String substitutions are not support for **loop** variables.