# Using the findstr command in a CMD file and expect ERRORLEVEL to be set. But it is not

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10, findstr, errorlevel

This line works:

```bash
findstr /I /C:"Archiving file" "..\LogFiles\%NewLogFileName%"
```

Outputting the following to the screen:

```
2023-08-21 13:25:11.9024|Info|Archiving file
```

The next line I am looking for `ERROR` in a file. I know that `ERROR` is NOT in the file, so my expectation is that the error level should be `1`, but it is continually `0`.

```bash
findstr /I /C:"ERROR" "..\LogFiles\%NewLogFileName%"

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
     ECHO Error level AFTER Search %ERRORLEVEL%
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Since this thread opened I have changed the code to:

```bash
findstr /I /C:"ERROR" "..\LogFiles\%NewLogFileName%"

call echo %%errorlevel%% & REM WORKS "1"

REM multiple iteration of these lines fail

REM Some things I have tried 
echo %errorlevel% & REM FAILS "0"

SET "somevar=%%errorlevel%%"

echo %somevar% & REM FAILS "0"
```

The text files are basic text. one has Archiving file in the contents the other DOES NOT HAVE error in the text.

What more can I provide?

Comment: Can't replicate - seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Please cut the relevant section of the code  and paste it into your question using the `edit` facility. Since `errorlevel` must be 1 or greater to display the `after search` message, I suspect that your code is within a block (parenthesised sequence of lines) and hence ot displays `errorlevel` as the value when the block was *parsed*. Try `call echo...%%errorlevel%%`.

Comment: @Magoo call echo %%errorlevel%% works. But why the "Call" and "%%" ? I have tried Echo %ERRORLEVEL% right after the search, and it always returned zero...Thank you!

Comment: @Stephan - what operating system? I am on Win 10

Comment: You didn't show relevant parts of your code (as Magoo guessed right). We need a reproducable problem to solve it. The answer to "why does this work" is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)

Comment: To be honest for the example you've shown, without a sample file content, I'd have used `find.exe`; either ```%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "ERROR" 0<"..\LogFiles\%NewLogFileName%"``` or for belt and braces, ```If Exist "..\LogFiles\%NewLogFileName%" (```, ```Type "..\LogFiles\%NewLogFileName%" | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "ERROR"```, ```If ErrorLevel 1 Echo Errorlevel AFTER Search 1```, ```)```. However as is clear, and I'd also guessed, you posted an incomplete code snippet, which did not reflect the actual problem. That would be a delayed expansion issue!

Comment: @compo This is all there is..... What more can I provide?

Comment: That in not technically true @AbbyNormal. I can say that because ```findstr /I /C:"ERROR" "..\LogFiles\%NewLogFileName%"``` would resolve to ```findstr /I /C:"ERROR" "..\LogFiles\"``` as you have not defined a variable named `NewLogFileName` anywhere in your code. Also by its very name, it is implied that other code exists too, otherwise this would not be a "New" Log File Name, if it existed before the batch file was invoked. Additionally without `Echo`ing `Off`, you'd have  much more output that that which you showed before my latest edit.

Comment: Run in a command prompt window `%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe findstr` exactly as written here (copy and paste the command line into the command prompt window). Is there output `C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe`? Yes, that is good. What does happen on putting this command line into your batch with appending `& pause` to halt the batch file execution to see the output and running the batch file? Is there also output `C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe`? Yes, then we know that at least the correct executable is run on using in the batch file just `findstr` instead of the fully qualified file name.

Comment: The __FINDSTR__ argument `"..\LogFiles\%NewLogFileName%"` references the environment variable `NewLogFileName`. How is this environment variable defined in your batch file? What is the current directory on execution of the batch file? Does the batch file define the current working directory? I recommend reading [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564) which means removing `@echo off` from top of the batch file and running it from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking on the batch file. How does the command line look on execution?

Comment: You might be interested also in [accessing the values of dynamic variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65979943/3074564). The first code posted by you should always work, except there is not executed `C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe` on using just `findstr` in the batch file. It is advisable to use in a batch file always the fully qualified file name of a Windows command. Then `cmd.exe` does not need to search for the executable (faster) and it cannot happen running something completely different than expected making the batch file execution more fail-safe and secure.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
findstr /ic:"error" "..\LogFiles\%NewLogFileName%" >nul && echo/0 || echo/1
```

---

If your path/file exists or doesn't exist, if the string was found or not, forget `errorlevel`, use operators **`&&`** *return 0* and **`||`** *return non 0*.

**[`Findstr /flag(s) <file.eXt`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)** **[`&& (do BC Return 0) || (do BC Return non 0)`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

```
FINDSTR will set %ERRORLEVEL% as follows:

    0 (False) a match is found in at least one line of at least one file.
    1 (True) if a match is not found in any line of any file, (or if the file is not found at all).
    2 Wrong syntax 
    
    An invalid switch will only print an error message in error stream;
```

---

```bash
@echo off 

command 1
command 2
command ...
command n
 
findstr /ic:"strings xy" <"..\Log\%New%" >nul && (
     command 1
     command 2
     command ...
     command n
     echo/0 
    ) || (
     command 1
     command 2
     command ...
     command n
     echo/1 
    )

command 1
command 2
command ...
command n
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`FindSTR /?`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As the batch langiage has evolved, the original line-by-line nature has been retained, but the concept of a "line" has changed to that of a "logical line".

Lines may now contain multiple commands separated by `&`. This has been extended to allow conditional execution by `&&` and `||`

Lines may be extended over multiple physical lines by using the line-continuation symbol `^` or by grouping commands within parentheses (know on SO as a `block`)

Since we sometimes need to use a character that is used as part of the language as a literal, we can "escape" the character (turn off the special meaning of the following character) by preceding it with a caret `^` - but the escape character for `%` is another `%`.

Quite how a logical line is executed is covered in [this short article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/2128947)

Hence, when a logical line is parsed, any `%var%` found on the line is replaced by the value of that variable at that time - the time the line is parsed, before execution commences.

So the fragment `call echo %%errorlevel%%` is interpreted as `call echo {escaped-%}errorlevel{escaped-%}` and is executed in a sub-process as `echo %errorlevel%`.

Another approach is the use of [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947)