# Calling secrets stored in powershell secretsmanagement as env variables in batch script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to store credentials used in a batch script in powershell with the secretsmanagement module. I want to be able to call credentials stored such as username and password into a batch script as environment variables.

I currently have 2 scripts:

1. Powershell script that calls the credentials and saves them as environmental variables
2. Batch script

It seems that the current script I have set up is failing to read the credentials as the batch file keeps trying to log into the server with my computer's username instead of the credentials i've stored in ps.

PS script

```
# Retrieve USERNAME and convert it to plain text
$usernameSecureString = (Get-Secret -Name 'USERNAME1' -Vault 'XX')
$ptrUsername = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode($usernameSecureString)
$usernamePlainText = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringUni($ptrUsername)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode($ptrUsername)

# Retrieve PASSWORD as a SecureString and convert it to plain text
$passwordSecureString = (Get-Secret -Name 'PASSWORD1' -Vault 'XX')
$ptrPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode($passwordSecureString)
$passwordPlainText = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringUni($ptrPassword)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode($ptrPassword)

# Set the credentials as environment variables for the process
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME", $usernamePlainText, "Process")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PASSWORD", $passwordPlainText, "Process")
```

Batch script

```
:: Call the PowerShell script to set the environment variables
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File [file path to PS script]

echo Username: %USERNAME%
echo Password: %PASSWORD%

...
```

The PS script works because i am able to retrieve the secrets with:
`Write-Host "Retrieved USERNAME: $usernamePlainText"`

any idea what I can do...

Comment: Please take a look on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) There is described where persistent stored __user__ or __system__ environment variables are stored in the Windows registry. The chapter __F)__ describes how __local__ environment variables in memory of a running process like `powershell.exe` in your case are handled.

Comment: `USERNAME` is a predefined __user__ [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) which is defined by the Windows shell. See  [Difference between Dynamic Environment Variables and Normal Environment Variables in CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65979943/3074564) for more information about environment variables defined by Windows shell for each user account.

Comment: The child process `powershell.exe` defines in its own process memory the environment variables `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD`. When `powershell.exe` terminates, its process memory is released by Windows and gets back into the pool of free memory blocks. The parent process `cmd.exe` processing the batch file has no read access to the memory of the temporarily started child process `powershell.exe`. It is impossible for `cmd.exe` making use of the environment variables defined by `powershell.exe` in its process memory as long as running.

Comment: A solution could be throwing away the batch file processed by `cmd.exe` and use just `powershell.exe` with a *PowerShell* script file doing everything including the actions done currently by the batch file. Otherwise if it is absolutely necessary that `cmd.exe` gets defined in its own process memory environment variables with string values stored secure and read by *PowerShell* from secure storage, the batch file should pass a file name to the *PowerShell* script as argument like `"%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"` into which the *PowerShell* scripts writes the command lines: `set "VariableName=Value"`.

Comment: The batch file contains as next line after `Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File [file path to PS script] "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"` the command line `if exist "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp" call "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp" & del "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"`. That is not really secure but at least the environment variables are defined now in the memory of `cmd.exe` processing the batch file. Another solution would be that the *PowerShell* outputs to `stdout` the environment variable names with equal sign and string value enclosed in `"` and there is used in the batch file:

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File [file path to PS script]') do set %%I`. That results in execution of `set "VariableName=Value"` for each line `"VariableName=Value"` output by the *PowerShell* script file to `stdout`. That solution is a bit more secure as the string values of the environment variables are never stored in any file on the hard disk in a readable form. Hint: Do not redefine the predefined environment variable `USERNAME`. Use `NAMEUSER` as variable name.